# How can we find the function of a circle

Tags: analysis

What is the proof that $x^2+y^2=r^{2}$ is a circle? How can we find the function of a circle?

Comment: You can't calculate a function of a circle - calculations are for numbers only. What do you mean in your last question?

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: @Toby Mak The OP surely means "cartesian equation(s) $y=f(x)$". Transform $x^2+y^2=r^2$ into $y^2=r^2-x^2$ giving rise to **two** cartesian equations : $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ (upper part, above $x$ axis) and  $y= - \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ (lower part)

Comment: @Jean Marie The definition of a circle as being the locus of all points $r$ away from a point $(a,b)$ works perfectly fine as well.

Answer (score 3):

Definition of a circle: set of points in a plane whose distance from a center is equal.

Formula for the distance of the point $(x,y)$ from the origin: $d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Putting these two together, you get the equation of a circle centered at the origin. Square both sides to make it nice.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pythagoras's theorem, for a circle centered at $(a,b)$, the horizontal distance to a point on that circle $(x,y)$ is $(x-a)$, and the vertical distance is $(y-b)$. Using Pythagoras's theorem, we have $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2$, where $r$ is the radius of the circle.

Since a circle is defined as the locus of all points from a point, which is $(a,b)$ in this situation, for each value of $(x,y)$ there is only one point. However, when there are infinitely many values for $(x,y)$, there are infinitely many points that are $r$ away from $(a,b)$, which satisfies the definition of the circle.

[image]

Note: In your case, $(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2 = r^2$, so $a,b = 0$, and your circle is centered on the point $(0,0)$.